# Garden Mushroom Identification

Tags: species-identification, mushroom

[image]

Could someone please identify this mushroom? 
Found in a garden situated in a mild Western European country.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looks like [shaggy ink cap, *Coprinus comatus*,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprinus_comatus?wprov=sfsi1) to me.

[Blacksmith37's answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/62617/32431) suggests that shaggy mane is the usual common name. I hadn't heard that name until I looked at the Wikipedia page. In the U.K. it is shaggy ink cap, inkytop, inkhorn or lawyer's wig.

**Update**

[This](http://www.wildfooduk.com/mushroom-guides/shaggy-ink-caps-mushroom/) is a good general source of information. Also *comatus* (Latin) means *hairy*.

Answer (score 2):

I think the more common name is Shaggy Mane , related to "inkies" and "micas". It is too old to eat when it gets pink, then black liquid. In the Midwest US they come up early spring and fall in the same spots. .... Sorry,I meant to imply that was the name in the US. It is a good beginner mushroom ; hard to confuse with anything poison.

Comment: Re: "too old to eat" (or rather, the implied inverse). The standard disclaimer applies: **Never** rely on identification from random people on the internet to determine if a mushroom is safe to eat. Also, never consume any mushroom you're not 100% sure is edible.

Comment: ^^ from the wikipedia article on the mushroom: "The mushroom can sometimes be confused with the magpie fungus which is poisonous."

Comment: So... Does the goo actually act as a stable pigment?

Comment: @TheNate No - in fact the inkcap fungus is unusual, in that if it is harvested, or after it has shed its spores, the whole "cap" turns into black goo and auto-digests itself! But they are good to eat if they are picked young and eaten as soon as possible after picking.

Comment: By the way, don't eat this mushroom and consume alcohol. There is a substance in the mushroom (marketed as drug under the name *Antabus*) causing a prolonged hangover.